# Nielsen-Schreier with operations

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-actions, free-groups

The Nielsen-Schreier theorem states that subgroups of a free subgroup are free.
Is this hold also for groups with operations?

Explicitly, let $G$ be a fixed group. Let $F$ be a group with $G$-action which is free (as a group with $G$-action). Let $F'\subset F$ be a subgroup closed by the $G$-action. Then, must $F$ be free as a group with $G$-action?

Comment: What exactly is meant by "free as a group with $G$-action"? My guess is that it means "free with basis a $G$-set", is that correct? Also, do you know of any references discussing such groups with operators?

Comment: @MarkGrant the definition of being a free $G$-group is not what you say, but a certain universal property in the category of $G$-groups. Yet, a *characterization* is: a $G$-group is free (as $G$-group) if and only if it admits a subset $X$ such that $X$ is a free $G$-subset, and $G$ is freely generated by $X$ as group.

Comment: A counterexample is the free $(Z/2Z)$-group on a single generator, as replied below by მამუკა ჯიბლაძე. This is the first test-case for such a question...

Comment: The question would be maybe less obvious if one restricts to $G$ free (on a set $I$), so that a $G$-group is a group endowed with a family (indexed by $I$) of automorphisms.

Comment: @YCor I guess in that case (of $G$ free) it would be easy to perform Nielsen-Schreier on the quotient by the $G$-action (which will be a free group) and then lift the result back...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე the quotient by the $G$-action is not a group. You mean, the quotient by the normal subgroup generated by the $(g\cdot w)w^{-1}$ when $g$ ranges over $G$ and $w$ over the given free $G$-group?

Comment: @YCor I had in mind to use the surjective homomorphism from a free $G$-group to the free group with the same free generating set (which I think is the same that you describe). This exists for any $G$, while for $G$ free I thought it might behave especially well by having $G$-free preimages for every subgroup of the quotient...

Comment: But on the afterthought, - by far not all $G$-subgroups above will be preimages of subgroups below, most likely

Comment: @YCor: I'm not sure I agree with your characterisation of the universal property. I would have thought that the definition of free $G$ group should be: $F$ is a free $G$-group if there is a $G$-subset $X\subseteq F$ such that $G$-homomorphisms from $F$ into another $G$-group $H$ are in natural correspondence with $G$-equivariant functions $X\to H$. Then I see no reason why $G$ should act freely on $X$.

Comment: But I guess there is some scope here for disagreement, hence why I asked if there is a canonical reference.

Comment: @MarkGrant I don't think there's disagreement, we agree on what should be the universal property defining a free $G$-group on a set $X$: this is a group $F$ along with a map $i:X\to F$, such that for every $G$-group $W$ and map $j:X\to W$ there is a unique $G$-group homomorphism $f:F\to W$ such that $f\circ i=j$. This is unique up to unique isomorphism of $G$-groups. (...)

Comment: (...) If $Y$ is a $G$-set, then the free group $F_Y$ on $Y$ is naturally a $G$-group. Now endow $X\times G$ with the structure of $G$-set $g\cdot (x,h)=(x,gh)$; this is a free $G$-set, with orbits naturally indexed by $X$. Then $F_{X\times G}$ is a free $G$-group, on the set $X\times\{1\}$. Indeed, consider any map $X\to W$, $W$ a $G$-group. It extends uniquely to a $G$-map $X\times G\to W$, and the universal property of $F_{X\times G}$ as a group yields a unique extension $F_{X\times G}\to W$, which is a group homomorphism. The uniqueness implies that the latter is also $G$-equivariant.

Comment: @YCor: Ah, right. As I understand it, what you describe is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from $G$-groups to sets, while what I'm describing is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from $G$-groups to $G$-sets. Both seem equally valid and useful definitions to me.

Comment: @MarkGrant I agree that the latter definition is useful (since it results in a strictly more general notion), but in general "free" in any kind of structure of universal algebra refers to the left-adjoint of the forgetful functor to $G$-sets. Other bear other names (tensorial algebra, symmetric algebra, enveloping algebra, etc).

Comment: In any cases, I believe the counterexample works for the both senses of "free"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $G$ be a two element group; the free group on two generators $x,y$ with the action of $G$ interchanging them is a free $G$-group (on one generator). Its subgroup generated by $xy^{-1}$ is closed under the $G$-action but is not a free $G$-group.

Comment: of course... didn't thought of that