# Projective G-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-actions, free-groups

Let $G$ be a fixed group. By definition, a $G$-group is a group $X$ with a $G$-action that respects the group operation of $X$. A free $G$-group means a group freely generated by a free $G$-set. A "projective $G$-group" means a projective object in the category of $G$-groups.

Can there be projective $G$-groups which are not free $G$-groups?
If yes, for which groups $G$ does it happen?

Comment: What is a $G$-group?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313860/nielsen-schreier-with-operations (a $G$-subgroup of a free $G$-group can fail to be a free $G$-group).

Comment: @abx $G$-group is a group with a $G$-action, which is compatible with the group operation

Comment: As discussed in the comments to the question YCor links to, there are 2 possible definitions of free $G$-group. Unlike that question, I suspect the answer here depends on which definition you choose.

Answer (score 1):

No (there do not exist projective $G$-groups which are not free $G$-groups).

By standard arguments, a $G$-group is projective if and only if it is a retract of a free $G$-group. So we only have to show that a retract of a free $G$-group is a free $G$-group.

This is not immediate, [because a $G$-subgroup of a free $G$-group need not be a free $G$-group](https://mathoverflow.net/a/313877/8103), as noted in the comments. However it follows from considerations of equivariant group cohomology.

Let $H$ be a $G$-group, and let $M$ be a $\mathbb{Z}[H\rtimes G]$-module. Cegarra, García-Calcines and Ortega define the equivariant group cohomology of $H$ with coefficients in $M$ to be $H^*(H\rtimes G,G;M)$, the Takasu relative cohomology of the pair (which agrees with the singular cohomology of the pair $(B(H\rtimes G),BG)$ for suitably chosen classifying spaces). This has the usual functoriality properties for homomorphisms of $G$-groups. Define the *equivariant cohomological dimension* of the $G$-group $H$ to be the maximal $n$ such that $H^n(H\rtimes G,G;M)\neq 0$ for some coefficient module $M$.

In [a recent preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.08574) with Kevin Li, Ehud Meir and Irakli Patchkoria, we prove the following:

**Theorem:** A $G$-group has equivariant cohomological dimension $\le1$ if and only if it's a free $G$-group.

Now if the identity on $H$ factors as $H\to F\to H$ where $F$ is a free $G$-group, then the equivariant cohomological dimension of $H$ is less than or equal to $1$. Hence projective $G$-groups are free $G$-groups.

(Actually this is just one of three possible definitions of equivariant cohomological dimension, which are compared in the preprint.)

Comment: Since my comment is no longer relevant, I have deleted it (and will delete this one soon).

Comment: Mark, maybe I’m missing something but if you have two non trivial groups $G, K$, a free $G$ group is a retract of a free $G\times K$ group so it should be projective over the product.

Comment: @FernandoMuro I'm not sure I understand. In order to view a free $G$-group as a retract of a free $G\times K$-group, I have to first view it as a $G\times K$-group. I could do this by letting the $K$ act trivially...but then it won't generally give a free $G\times K$-group (thinking of the case where $G$ and $K$ are finite, you could have a free $G$ group of rank $|G|$, which cannot have a free basis of cardinality a multiple of $|G\times K|$). In short, how do you move back and forth between the category of $G$-groups and the category of $G\times K$-groups?

Comment: @MarkGrant I somehow imagined that the retraction $\langle G\times K\rangle\twoheadrightarrow \langle G\rangle\hookrightarrow \langle G\times K\rangle$ was $G\times K$-equivariant, which obviously isn't (the section fails).